# AppHarbor: Connecting to a MySQL DB via ASP.NET MVC 5 + Dapper

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, dapper, appharbor

I'm trying to get an application up and running on AppHarbor.  It's been smooth sailing for the most part, but today I'm having trouble connecting to my MySQL database.

Using the credentials AppHarbor provided me with, I successfully connected to the mySQL database instance using dbForge Studio Express, created the necessary SQL schema, and populated the tables with data.  Now I'm trying to use the following C# code to do a simple query using Dapper:

```
var sqlConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppHarborMySql"].ConnectionString);

using (var db = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    db.Open();
    // Do database query stuff

    return result;
}
```

But this is the error that I'm running into, when I try to open the database connection:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

This is how I've declared the connection string in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppHarborMySql" connectionString="server=MYDOMAIN.mysql.sequelizer.com;database=MYDBNAME;uid=MYUSERNAME;pwd=MYPASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.x and the latest version of Dapper... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, despite having spent the better part of an hour investigating, I discover the answer immediately after posting the question.

For anyone else who may run across the same problem: I added the [MySql.Web NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Web/) to my MVC project, added `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` to the top of my page, and then changed my code to point from `SqlConnection` to `MySqlConnection`.  Here's what my working code block now looks like:

```
using (var db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppHarborMySql"].ConnectionString))
{
    db.Open();
    // Do database query stuff

    return result;
}
```